# POST request with Perl and read response object within dancer route

Tags: perl, https, request, response, dancer

Trying to write the exact equivalence in perl of the following:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user": { "uid":"13453"},"access_token":"3428D3194353750548196BA3FD83E58474E26B8B9"}' https://platform.gethealth.io/v1/health/account/user/
```

Unexperienced with perl, this is what I have tried:

```
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::UserAgent;

get '/gethealthadduser/:id' => sub {
  my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
  $ua->request(POST 'https://platform.gethealth.io/v1/health/account/user', [{"user": { "uid":param("id")},"access_token":config->{gethealthtoken}}]);
};
```

Comment: no error but I only see the call to the dancer route(get /gethealthadduser) on the network console, not the post request

Comment: "the network console" — do you mean the one in the browser's Developer Tools? Since that is being made from Perl to the server, the browser isn't involved, so there is no reason for the browser to know about it.

Comment: Thank you, good point :p

Comment: but the second request should appear in my perl console, and does not

Comment: No, it would not appear in your Dancer log unless you write it to the log.

Comment: Which Perl console? Do you have one for the server hosting `https://platform.gethealth.io/v1/health/account/user`?

Comment: no  only for the app that issues the call to gethealth.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you are working with Dancer already, or you are adding something to an existing application, and the goal is to hide the POST request to another service behind your API.

In your curl example, you have the Content-Type `application/json`, but in your Perl code you are sending a form. That's likely going to be the Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It might not be what the server wants.

In addition to that, you were passing the form data as an array reference, which makes `POST` believe they are headers. That not what you want.

In order to do the same thing you are doing with curl, you need a few more steps.

- You need to convert the data to JSON. Luckily Dancer brings [a nice DSL keyword `to_json`](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#to_json-structure-options) that does that easily.
- You need to tell LWP::UserAgent to use the right Content-Type header. That's `application/json` and you can set it either at the request level, or as a default for the user agent object. I'll do the former.
- In addition to that, I recommend not using HTTP::Request::Common to import keywords into a Dancer app. `GET` and `POST` and so on are upper-case and the Dancer DSL has `get` and `post` which is lower-case, but it's still confusing. Use [HTTP::Request](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Request) explicitly instead.

Here's the final thing.

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;

get '/gethealthadduser/:id' => sub {
    my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(
        POST => 'https://platform.gethealth.io/v1/health/account/user',
        [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ],                                   # headers
        to_json { user => param("id"), access_token => config->{gethealthtoken} },  # content
    );

    my $res = $ua->request($req);

    # log the call with log level debug
    debug sprintf( 'Posted to gethealth.io with user %s and got a %s back.', 
        param('id'), 
        $res->status_line
    );

    # do things with $res
};
```

Comment: thank you @simbabque the request is sent but im getting a 301 response. Think it is because the curl post passes parameters as `{"user": { "uid":"13453"},"access_token":"3428D3194353750548196BA3FD83E58474E26B8B9"}`

Comment: You can use `\`...\`` to highlight code in comments. The ``` character is called backtick and is on the left of the `1` key on a US keyboard. The way you posted it I don't understand. Quotes and things matter here. Please refer to the markdown help if you don't know what I'm talking about. ;)

Comment: @Ax so you get a redirect? That's probably good. It might redirect you to the URL of the new user object. Curl just puts the JSON string into the request body, right? Anyway a 3xx response code is not an error.

Answer (score 2):

Try using HTTP::Tiny (it's on CPAN).  IMHO, it's a much cleaner module than LWP::UserAgent, although the latter is much more popular.

Here's some code that should work out of the box:

```
use HTTP::Tiny 0.064;  # use a recent version or better

my $url = 'https://api.somewhere.com/api/users';
my $data = {
  first_name => "joe",
  last_name => "blow"
};
my $method = 'POST';


my $default_headers = {
  'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$token,  # if needed
  'Accept' => 'application/json'
};

my $tiny = HTTP::Tiny->new(
  agent => 'mywebsite.com',
  default_headers => $default_headers,
  timeout => 30
);

my $response;
if ( ($method eq 'POST') || ($method eq 'PUT') ) {
  $response = $tiny->request($method, $url, {
    headers => {
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    },
    content => &toJSON($data)
  });
}
else {
  if ($data) {
    die "data cannot be included with method $method"; 
  }
  $response = $tiny->request($method, $url); 
}

die unless $response->{'success'};
```

Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution with the correct format and structure of posted parameters:

```
get '/api/gethealthadduser/:id' => sub {
    my %user = (
        uid  => param("id")
    );
    # my $user = {
    #     uid  => param("id")
    # };

    my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new;
    my $req = HTTP::Request->new(
        POST => 'https://platform.gethealth.io/v1/health/account/user/',
        [ 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ],                                   # headers
        JSON::to_json({ user => \%user, access_token => config->{gethealthtoken} })  # content
    );
    my $res = $ua->request($req);
    print STDERR Dumper($res);
    $res;
};
```

Comment: @simbabque few minor fixes on top of your solution: `to_json {` => `JSON::to_json({` ,  param structure of `my %user` and url ending with `/` if you apply edits I´ll accept your answer, thanks again